# Is this alternator W RPM input circuit ok and how can I improve it?

Tags: signal-integrity, digital-filter, rpm

I need a robust and reliable way of taking a RPM signal from the W terminal of a standard automotive alternator. Most of the time the signal will come from a 12V alternator but there is a requirement for it to be compatible with 24V (28v when charging).

Here is what the signal looks like straight from the alternator:
[image: RPM output]

I have used this circuit to convert it into a 3.3V DC signal:
[image: 2N2222 Circuit]

and I then get this signal at the same RPM:
[image: 2N2222 output]

so far so good but when I triple the RPM a lot of noise is introduced like this:
[image: Fast RPM]
the time in-between the lines here is around 928µS.

**(Update)** The noise however seems to be introduced at the input as this is the waveform from the alternators W output at the same speed:
[image]

I have added a 10K resistor at the output to the MCU and the output waveform now looks like this:
[image]
Red is without the resistor, blue is with.

So my questions are:

Is the noise in the last picture a problem, if so how do I get rid of it?

Is this signal (with or without the noise) suitable and reliable to feed into a MCU to read RPM?

How can I improve the circuit to make it reliable and robust for production grade products?

Starting from scratch what would be the most reliable circuit?

Comment: What does the original signal look like at this new rpm?

Comment: Good point, I'll scope the output at this RPM to workout where the noise is being introduced and I'll update my question.

Comment: It looks like the noise is at the input, I have since updated

Answer (score 0):

You may use an RC filter with a time constant of approx 50% of worst case max pulse width RPM period then **use a CMOS Schmitt trigger inverter** which has 33% hysteresis to **reject noise between approx 1/3 and 2/3 Vcc after low pass filter and proper divide ratio to scale.**

- But for CMOS ground the unused inputs.
- But you can also make a one-shot out of these gates with a diode cap resistor and 5Vreg to make the Tach voltage directly by averaging the 1-shot output in DC with a similar filter as before, except now **RC will be about 20ms**. depending on the desired slew rate. ...vroom...  except at idle the freq. may be too low and flutter he voltage so a CMOS transmission gate can be used as a S&H to eliminate the flutter using the new clock and filtered DC Tach signal.

Thus if the maximum interval of the pulse or frequency is 10kHz or 50us "high" then use a 5us time constant = RC.

Also, **use twisted pair** (UTP or STP) to reduce spark plug crosstalk or whatever is causing this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flz4PG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- or use 3.3V
- Don't forget different vehicles have different pulley ratios that affect Alternator/Motor RPM ratios.